# Выбор языка php

Tags: php, html

Всем привет! Пытаюсь сделать выбор языка на php, но что идет не так
Собственно вывожу флаг активного языка:

```html
<img src="<?php echo $langs[LANG_TAG]['file']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $langs[LANG_TAG]['title']; ?>">
```

И остальные языки:

```html
<?php
    foreach($langs as $row) {
        $title_lang = $row['title']; ?>
        <a href="<?php echo DOCBASE.$row['tag']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $row['file']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $title_lang; ?>"> </a>
<?php } ?>
```

Но проблема в том - что активный язык выводится 2 раза! 
Я так понимаю что нужно условие: активный язык - не выводить в foreach($langs as $row)! Подскажите как это сделать! Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно угадал, то должен такой код отработать:

```
<?php
foreach($langs as $tag => $row){
    if (LANG_TAG == $tag) {
        continue;
    }
    $title_lang = $row['title']; ?>
    <a href="<?php echo DOCBASE.$row['tag']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $row['file']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $title_lang; ?>"> </a>
<?php
} ?>
```

`LANG_TAG` - это константа с тега языка как я понял, в `$langs` ключи и есть теги языков